# It's even possible to decide which modules should be loaded into app?

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I need to solve a question from my title.
For eg. i need to make two different version of app, one for france and one for UK. In few places they have totally different implementation. It's possible to swap components on build (for eg. Sale_en_GB.module for Sale_fr_FR.module)? If not, it's possible for components (with same naming pattern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app routing module, you can create a guard that only shows depending on country:

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules, NoPreloading } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/services/auth.guard';

const gbRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: 'gb',
  loadChildren: () => import('./Sale_en_GB/Sale_en_GB.module').then(mod => mod.SalesGBModule),
  canLoad: [CountryGuard],
}];
const frRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: 'fr',
  loadChildren: () => import('./Sale_fr_FR/Sale_fr_FR.module').then(mod => mod.SalesFRModule),
  canLoad: [CountryGuard],
}];

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'gb', //default
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent, //there will be a main component for both modules.
    canActivate: [CountryGuard],
    children: [
      ...gbRoutes,
      ...frRoutes,
    ]
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*auth.guard.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad, Route, UrlSegment, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router, Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad, Resolve<any> {
  token: any;
  user: any;
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(){
    if (checkCountry('GB')) { //find a way to check user country
        this.router.navigate(['/gb']);
    } else if(checkCountry('FR')) {
        this.router.navigate(['/fr']);
    }
    return false;
  }

  canActivateChild(){
    return true;
  }

  canLoad(){
    if (checkCountry('GB')) { //find a way to check user country
        this.router.navigate(['/gb']);
    } else if(checkCountry('FR')) {
        this.router.navigate(['/fr']);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```